# Я пишу бота для телеграмма используя библиотеку telebot и я хочу сделать кнопку назад. Как я могу сделать ее?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я нажимаю на кнопку south - west и у меня выдает название штатов но я хочу сделать чтобы когда я нажал на штат Алабама а потом мог вернуться и нажать на Кентукки

```
#SOUTH-WEST
elif message.text == 'SOUTH-WEST':
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn37 = types.KeyboardButton('Alabama')
    btn38 = types.KeyboardButton('Kentucky')
    btn39 = types.KeyboardButton('Mississippi')
    btn40 = types.KeyboardButton('Tennessee')
    btn41 = types.KeyboardButton('Arkansas')
    btn42 = types.KeyboardButton('Louisiana')
    btn43 = types.KeyboardButton('Oklahoma')
    btn44 = types.KeyboardButton('Texas')
    markup.add(btn37, btn38, btn39, btn40, btn41, btn42, btn43, btn44)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose your city!', reply_markup=markup)
elif message.text == "Alabama":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1$')
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
if message.text == 'SOUTH-WEST':
    global markup
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn37 = types.KeyboardButton('Alabama')
    btn38 = types.KeyboardButton('Kentucky')
    btn39 = types.KeyboardButton('Mississippi')
    btn40 = types.KeyboardButton('Tennessee')
    btn41 = types.KeyboardButton('Arkansas')
    btn42 = types.KeyboardButton('Louisiana')
    btn43 = types.KeyboardButton('Oklahoma')
    btn44 = types.KeyboardButton('Texas')
    markup.add(btn37, btn38, btn39, btn40, btn41, btn42, btn43, btn44)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose your city!', reply_markup=markup)
elif message.text == 'Alabama':
    markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btnback = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
    markup2.add(btnback)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1$', reply_markup=markup2)
elif message.text == 'Back':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose your city!', reply_markup=markup)
```